# OutOfMemoryException when Inserting larger images in SQL Server CE

Tags: image, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6.5, sql-server-ce-3.5

Inserting smaller images work fine. However, when the image file gets bigger than about 2MB, I get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I tried with `SqlCeUpdatableRecord` and a parameterized `SqlCeCommand`. Using the `SqlCeCommand`, the exception is raised at `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

With `SqlCeUpdatableRecord`, the exception is raised at `SqlCeUpdatableRecord.SetBytes()`.

I’ve tried increasing buffer size and temp file size without it seeming to have an effect. I've debugged with `GetTotalMemory` and there seems to be plenty of resources available.

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

The SQL Server CE database is synchronized with a main SQL Server database and handling images as separate files would introduce a truckload of other issues. The solution has worked fine for years as most WM handhelds only capture images at 5MP or less. However, newer models with support for 8MP images is causing issues.

Here is a simplified version of the `SqlCeUpdateblRecord` implementation:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeUpdatableRecord newRecord = base.CreateRecord();
newRecord["ImageId"] = ImageId;
newRecord["ImageType"] = ImageType;
//64kb buffer (Have tested with different buffer sizes (up to 8MB)
newRecord.SetBytesFromFile("ImageFull", ImageFullFileName, 65536);
newRecord["ImageThumb"] = ImageThumb;
newRecord["ImageDate"] = ImageDate;
base.Insert(newRecord); 

.....
public static void SetBytesFromFile(this SqlCeUpdatableRecord obj, string name, string filename, int buffersize)
{
    int _column = obj.GetOrdinal(name);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];            
    int bytesread;
    long offset = 0;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Open))
    {
        bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);

        while (bytesread > 0)
        {
            //This will raise OutOfMemoryException for imagefiles larger than appx. 2mb, regardless of buffersize      
            obj.SetBytes(_column, offset, buffer, 0, bytesread);                    
            offset = offset + (long)bytesread;
            bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);           
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simplified version of the paramterized query:

```
using (var cmdInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Image_CF] ( [ImageId], [ImageType], [ImageFull], [ImageThumb], [ImageDate]) VALUES " +
                                                   " ( @ImageId, @ImageType, @ImageFull, @ImageThumb, @ImageDate)"))
{
    cmdInsert.Connection = Database.IrisPdaConnection;

    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ImageId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = ImageId;
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ImageType", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ImageType;
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ImageFull", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image).Value = GetFileAsBytes(ImageFullFileName);
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ImageThumb", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image).Value = ImageThumb;
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ImageDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ImageDate;

    // OutOfMemoryException for images larger than appx. 2MB
    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

public byte[] GetFileAsBytes(string filename)
{
   FileStream fs;
   byte[] result;

   using (fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
        // a byte array to read the image
        result = new byte[fs.Length];     
        fs.Read(result, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));  
   }

   return result; 
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to store images in db? This is very bad practice. Can you post code that you use? Are you trying to store Bitmaps?

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I've updated the post with code examples. The images are jpg captured by the built-in camera.

Comment: Wonder if you could use SqlCeUpdateableRecord, add say 1 MB of data, insert, and find the row, and add more data to the column? Also, lower the resolution of the camera, and consider saving to the file syste,.. Also, what build of the SQL CE engine is used? Some image column related hotfixes are available

Comment: Thanks for the hotfix tip Erik. I will investigate this and report back if this helps. Reducing resolution is last resort (We recommend our users to purchase these newer models with better spec :/)

Comment: I applied hotfix 6 (3.5.8088.0) which is the latest build with device assemblies. No improvement I'm afraid.

Comment: I have decided to downscale the images as a workaround for the time being. Will leave the case open in the hope that someone else has managed to crack this one..